# C++ Win32 Having Trouble Aligning Text on a Pushbutton

Tags: c++, winapi, alignment

This should be fairly simple, but I cannot for the life of me figure out why its not working. I did a lot of googling and MSDN and couldn't find anything more useful.

```
    SendMessage(GetDlgItem(hwnd, IDC_ANCIENT), BM_SETSTYLE, (WPARAM)(BS_LEFTTEXT), (LPARAM)TRUE);
    Button_SetStyle(GetDlgItem(hwnd, IDC_ANCIENT), BS_LEFTTEXT, TRUE);
```

That's what I have. The parameters are right, I tested the style BS_3STATE, and it worked. I have it set to redraw. I have those lines within the WM_INITDIALOG message of the dialog.

The dialog and everything on it is contained in my resource files.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

http://imageshack.us/a/img153/6594/rydv.jpg

Comment: Is the button defined as a checkbox or a radio button? BS_LEFTTEXT only works for those button types. Also a screenshot of what you're seeing might be helpful.

Comment: Hmm, so is there any styles that will align the text left? I uploaded a screenshot of the resource file and the corresponding buttons.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I downloaded a resource file editor and found the solution.

```
           DEFPUSHBUTTON      "Ancient Crystal [Click]",IDC_ANCIENT,15,292,140,12, BS_LEFT
```

If you put the BS_LEFT style in the resource file it will align the text left.

EDIT: Final Note
I was trying to change the font alignnment within a Procedure that did not have the proper handle to the dialog. I was handing the procedure the handle to the main window.

Answer (score 2):

The BS_LEFTTEXT doesn't work for buttons. From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775951%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (emphasis added):

`BS_LEFTTEXT`
Places text on the left side of the radio button or check box **when combined with a radio button or check box style**. Same as the BS_RIGHTBUTTON style.

For what you want you probably need to do an owner-draw control. Check out the `BS_OWNERDRAW` style on that same link.

Comment: Yeah, that is what I have got to do. For anyone else who stumbles across this page, here is a link to a tutorial on custom controls: http://www.catch22.net/tuts/custom-controls.

Thanks.